# Trouble with embeddd Codable objects and Firestore in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following

```swift
class OrderBasket: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID  var id: String!
  var credits: Int! = 200
  var basketTotal: Int
  var orderLines: [OrderLine] = []
       
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case credits
    case basketTotal
    case orderLines
  }
}
```

and

```swift
class OrderLine: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String! = UUID ().uuidString
  var sku : String!
  var quantity : Int
  var lineTotal: Int
    
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case sku
    case quantity
    case lineTotal
  }
}
```

I am able to successfully read the data from Firestore. However, how do I extract the `orderLines`?

The following code works to read the `OrderBasket`. How do I get the `orderLines`?

```swift
db.collection("Basket").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
  guard let basket = querySnapshot?.data() else {
    print("No documents for basket")
    return
  }
  
  self.orderBasket.credits = (basket["credits"] as! Int)
  self.orderBasket.basketTotal = basket["basketTotal"] as! Int
}
```

`basket["orderLines"]` contains the data but how do I get it to the object?

I am using `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` BTW.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how your data is structured? A screenshot of how it is stored in Firestore would be useful.

Comment: `basket["orderLines"]` is presumably a `[[String: Any]]`, or an array of dictionaries. If it is, you must iterate through this array and convert each dictionary into an `OrderLine` object. You can give `OrderLine` a failable initializer that takes a `[String: Any]` dictionary and returns an optional `OrderLine` object or manually get each field from the dictionary and inject it into the initializer. Also, presumably, when you wrote the array of `OrderLine` objects to Firestore, you serialized it into a `[[String: Any]]` array of dictionaries (map) first.